# How to implement a real-time data logging/backup system?

Tags: logging, save, backup, recovery

I'm developing software which enables the user to log events in real time. Each event is extremely critical data to be captured, and any loss of said data needs to be prevented to the furthest (reasonable) extent.

I have implemented storage of each new event to a running temp file, which of course works on its own. However, this method could be bunk e.g. if the software crashes mid-write, thereby corrupting the data.

I could implement a round-robin system where each event is logged to multiple files, so that there is always at least one good copy in the event of data corruption. This would work, and the data could be simply restored from the most recent "good" file, however this feel clunky.

Is there an industry standard, professionally preferred, or generally accepted method to perform failsafe running data logging?

Thank you!

Comment: Writing to a message queue may be a reasonable option.

Comment: Could you provide more context? A message queue in memory? If so that would require a separate app-independent thread in case of crash. If you're talking about a message queue in a file, that is essentially what I have already implemented.

Comment: The message queue itself is a separate process, running on the same server or as an external service.  There are various host-native and 3rd-party options available.  But the idea is that it's designed to be a reliable and simple fast-write system which persists a message that can be more fully "processed" later.  So if the desired result is a log file then yet another background process can be polling the queue and writing to the file.  That background process can also handle other responses to the log messages, like sending emails for important messages, etc.